# How deferredresult of Spring MVC is sent back to client(angular js)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring MVC and AngularJS. The application basically does sync between selected tables from the two db instances. When sync is called the following service is called at the server end as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "configversion/{srcConfVersionId}/sync", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ModelAttribute(DEFAULT_MODEL_ATTR_NAME)
@ResponseBody
public CustomResponse syncConfigurations(@PathVariable Long srcConfVersionId, @RequestBody SyncDTO dto) {
    Date processingTime = new Date();
    dto.setSrcConfVersionId(srcConfVersionId);

    DeferredResult<Object> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    SyncProcessingTask task = new SyncProcessingTask( dataSyncService, deferredResult, srcConfVersionId, dto);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, processingTime);
    return new CustomResponse(deferredResult);
}
```

As far as i know the `DeferredResult` is used for async process where the result can be read in future.

From the front end side once the sync button is clicked it goes to new page which lists the results of sync. As the server continues in background the client shows the "In Progess" status. Now the question is how can i check the `DeferredResult` is changed from the AngularJS side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback methods of DeferredResult. Implement the following.

```
DeferredResult.onCompletion(Runnable callback);
```